Local functions of global variables in Blocks
I am very confused by the difference in behaviour of the following two functions:
f0[F_] := Block[{tmpf, tbl},
  tbl = F Cos[x];
  tmpf[x_] = tbl x^2;
  Print[DownValues@tmpf];
  tmpf[y]
  ]

which gives what I want for f0[1 + w x], i.e. y^2 (1 + w y) Cos[y] (in other words all possible x (from global x to those inside the Block) are recognized properly as the variables for the function tmpf.
A very similar function
f1[F_] := Block[{tmpf},
  tmpf[x_] = F Cos[x] x^2;
  Print[DownValues@tmpf];
  tmpf[y]
  ]

however, gives (1 + w x) y^2 Cos[y], i.e. it does not recognize the x from the argument as the pattern-x of tmpf. I added DownValues, which indeed shows that the functions are defined differently in the two cases. Why the additional tbl = F localizes x? (If we remove Block, then none of the examples works)
More generally, my problem is as follows: I have a global variable F that depends on x (but it is not defined as a proper function of x), I want to pass it to another function (Block, maybe) that creates for internal purposes a function tmpf of this same x and then use it inside this Block.

It's the injection of F into the def. of tmpf[] that causes the argument x to be rewritten as x$. See for instance this tech note: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#1131

In f0 "x" is a global variable. In f1 "x" is localized by the definition of "tmp[x_]"

@Daniel, what is the exact difference and why: in both functions we have "tmpf[x_]" present, so I do not understand the answer

@ Michael E2, could you please point at the exact rule that Mathematica applies here to change the `meaning' of x?

In f0 you first use "bl = F Cos[x];" Here x is clearly a global variable because it is not an argument.. Then you say "tmpf[x_] = tbl x^2"  Here x^2 is localized, but the x in tbl is still global. In f1 you say "tmpf[x_] = F Cos[x] x^2" Here x is localized.

Very generally and simplistically, just know that Mathematica tries to avoid name collisions. Its heuristics for how to do this might not match every scenario that every user might come up with. If F is an expression that includes Global`x, then creating your new function (f0, f1, whatever) should work without Module if you define it in the Global context. Of course, I'd say that this is pretty sloppy practice, but it will work (unless there is more info you haven't provided). If you provide more context, we can suggest better overall strategies for what you're trying to do.

@lericr I still do not understand why this particular example works the way it works. In fact, I found out that removing the whole Block construct and replacing it with (...) leads to the same two different confusing results. The context as I described: there is a global variable that depends on some known to me parameters, I need to turn this into a function of these params local for some Block/Module as to operate it

@John I don't know what replacing with (...) looks like, so I can't help you there.

@lericr I mean that the Block-wrap can be replaced with just (...) keeping the rest unchanged, so that all the lines are in the definition of the same function f. The result will be the same: the two functions will give different answers, which seems to be a simplified form of the original question, but if you could answer the original question, that would help

Well, if the original question is "why do the two functions behave differently?", that has been answered by others in the comments. If the original question is "how to make such-and-such work?", I tried to answer that. I doubt that my answer is sufficient, but I don't have enough context to do better with specificity. I will say that this whole approach seems misguided to me. I'm virtually certain that you can solve your actual problem with a much cleaner design.

I usually do it this way: f1[F_] := Block[{tmpf},   tmpf[x0_] := Block[{x = x0}, F Cos[x] x^2];   Print[DownValues@tmpf];   tmpf[y]]

To try to address this

I am just trying to understand why Mathematica gives two different answers in these two cases

let's walk through some evaluations. Let's pare this down to a minimum.
test1[y_] := tmp1[x_] = y + x;
DownValues[test1]
(* {HoldPattern[test1[y_]] :> (tmp1[x_] = y + x)} *)

DownValues[tmp1]
(* {} *)

test1[z]
(* x$ + z *)

DownValues[tmp1]
(* {HoldPattern[tmp1[x$_]] :> x$ + z} *)

The question that jumps out is why is tmp1 defined with x$? I don't know the exact details of how Set/SetDelayed is defined internally, but clearly some effort was put in to avoid name collisions. As soon as we evaluate the SetDelayed expression to define test1, y, x, and tmp1 will exist in the Global context, but tmp1 will not have any DownValues (i.e. that particular Set expression hasn't actually been evaluated).
Now, when we evaluate test1[z], we need to bind z to y. But y appears inside of a Set expression, and so by some heuristic being used under the covers, Mathematica decides that there is the potential for a name collision (maybe z could depend on x, who knows?) and so takes time out to swap x for x$ before proceeding to evaluate the Set.
Compare that with the following.
test2[y_] := (body = y + x; tmp2[x_] = body);
DownValues[test2]
(* {HoldPattern[test2[y_]] :> (body = y + x; tmp2[x_] = body)} *)

test2[z]
(* x + z *)

DownValues[tmp2]
(* {HoldPattern[tmp2[x_]] :> x + z} *)

In this case, when we go to evaluate test2[z] we need to bind z to y. The Set expression for tmp2 doesn't contain y, so that particular heuristic is not applied this time (and it's not needed for body). Once the bindings are finished, we continue the evaluation. We set body to z+x and then we use that expression to define tmp2. We snuck z in under the cover of body and so didn't trigger the renaming.

[Extended response to comment]
You can do this:
F = 7 x;
y[x_] = F Cos[x];

y[17]
(* 119 Cos[17] *)

If that's not what you're trying to do, then we need more info. And again, I'd recommend that you don't do that at all, but I can't recommend anything without further info/context.

I am just trying to understand why Mathematica gives two different answers in these two cases. Nobody answered this yet in detail, but the second comment by Daniel almost does it for me. The second question is how to define a function in a Block/Module from the external object that is not  (explicitly) a function of the desired variables, which is answered by the last Michael comment.
